# How do i display the javascript error object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js and Express web application framework and 
mysql package from here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

here's my Parent.js file .. it's my model file

```
var db = require('../dbconnection');
var Parent = {
findIfParentMobileNumberExists: function (parentmobilenumber, callback) {
    db.query('SELECT parentmobilenumber from parents where parentmobilenumber=?', parentmobilenumber, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }
        if (rows.length < 1) {
            console.log("rows length less than 1");
            callback(err, null);

        }
        else if (rows.length !== 0) {
            console.log("rows length greater than 1");
            callback(null, rows[0].parentmobilenumber);
        }
        else {

        }

    });

}

module.exports = Parent;
```

and here's my registerParent.js file .. this is my route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Parent = require('../models/Parent');

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    var countrycode = req.body.countrycode;
    var parentmobilenumber = (countrycode) + (req.body.inputMobileNumber);

    //remove hyphens from mobile number
    var parentmobilenumberwithouthyphens =
    parentmobilenumber.replace(/-/g, "");

    //remove spaces from mobile number
    var parentmobilenumberwithouthyphensandspaces =
    parentmobilenumberwithouthyphens.replace(/ /g, '');

Parent.findIfParentMobileNumberExists(parentmobilenumberwithouthyphensandspaces, function (err, parentmobilenumberfromdb) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({registerErrorMessage: err.message});
    }
    else {
        if (parentmobilenumberwithouthyphensandspaces === parentmobilenumberfromdb) {
            console.log(parentmobilenumberfromdb);
        }
        else {
            res.json({registerErrorMessage: 'The Mobile Number does not exist in our database'});
        }

    }

});
});
```

if i enter a correct mobile number i get the mobile number displayed in a console.log message .. however when i enter an incorrect mobile number which is not in the database the resulting rows.length is < 1

i get the message 
rows length less than 1
but i don't understand when this block runs

```
if (rows.length < 1) {
        console.log("rows length less than 1");
        callback(err, null);

    }
```

the err object is never displayed .. i.e this block is never run in the router.post function

```
if (err){
res.json({registerErrorMessage: err.message});
}
```

so i want to display the err object correctly first ..
and then i want to display an error message that is readable by end-users 
how can i do this ?

i tried reading the documentation here
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#error-handling

but i really don't understand how to properly execute callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't start http server with express.

Try to insert code below to start listening:

```js
const app = express();

app.listen( insert port here )
```

Comment: i'm using webstorm .. i already have this statement this in another file

Comment: Have you tried to insert console.log next to res.json({registerErrorMessage: err.message}), in order to ensure that this part of corde is not being reached?


It looks more like networking error than unreachable code.

Comment: that statement does execute when there is a database level error but i want to display error when the rows.length < 1

Comment: how would i return a custom error though ? any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry, a fix: `        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }` sends response first before you can reach `        if (rows.length < 1) {
            console.log("rows length less than 1");
            callback(err, null);

        }`

Comment: You can send only one response per request.

Comment: And BTW, regarding custom errors: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Error

Answer (score 0):

At first, you might want to terminate your logic if an error occurs:

```
if(err){
  return callback(err);
}
```

Now the error is passed to the client side, where you can catch it and display a message. E.g. (using jquery):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"your/backend",
  dataType: "json",
  success(res){
    if(res.code){
       return alert("an error ("+res.code+") occured. Sorry :/");
    }
    //continue with valid response
  }
});
```

---

However, you may change your API to be more general, e.g. always return an error property, thats either false or the error object:

on error:

```
res.json({error:err});
```

on success:

```
res.json({error:false,data:"whatever"});
```

So that you could do this on client side:

```
    $.ajax({
  url:"your/backend",
  dataType: "json",
  success(res){
    if(res.error){
       return alert("an error ("+res.error.code+") occured. Sorry :/");
    }
    //continue with valid response
    alert(res.data);
  }
});
```